# iOS: dateformatter in swift return nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have this code in my app

```
service.requestLastDate{ (response) -> () in

        var str = response as NSString

            var d = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "")

            println("D \(str)") // D 2015-05-25 08:13:33

            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

            var date_formatted = dateFormatter.dateFromString(d)

            println("DATE FORMATTED \(date_formatted)") // is NIL
```

with this code date_formatted is ever nil. 
If I print in consolle "d" the result is "2015-02-12 08:15:16", this string is a real string.
If I try to use the string "example" I get a correct date_formatted.
What happen? 
I can't understand.
I just tried changing NSLocale and the timezone for the dateFormatter but I have ever the same result.

this is the request

```
func requestLastDate(completion:(response:NSString)->()){

        my_req_date = request(.GET, "http://example.com/current_date")
            .responseString { (_, _, string, error) in

            println(" server \(string!)") //server "2015-05-25 08:13:33"
            completion(response: string!)

        }
    }
```

Comment: yes if formatted as example!!! I'm going to be crazy

Comment: This looks strange. What about Swift and XCode version ?

Comment: My assumption is `d == "\"2015-02-12 08:15:16\""`

Comment: @rintaro that would print double quotes in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to break it :)

Think it might be:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

not

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
```

?

Comment: Oh YES!!! but now!!! Before the formatter was complete, also with seconds... I think that I solved my problem deleting the quote char from string

Answer (score 0):

Check your respsonse for that it translates to a proper date-formatted string. Because if I try this, it works:

```
var response:AnyObject?
response = "2015-03-17 23:34:12"

if let date:AnyObject = response {

    var d = date as! String
    var example = "2015-03-17 23:34:12"

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    var date_formatted = dateFormatter.dateFromString(d)
}
```

Comment: but here, you're using response as my string "example", in this way it work fine... the problem is that my response is well formatted but it doesn't work

Comment: What's the type of response? Because obviously the problem lies not in your code here but in where response is constructed.